# How do you require() a sound file in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound to play sounds on my iOS (and Android) app, and I'm trying to include sound files through React Native's asset system, but when I call:

`var sound = require('./sound.mp3');`

I get the error:

> Unable to resolve module ./sound.mp3 from [project]/index.ios.js: Invalid directory [project]/sound.mp3

I have my MP3 file in the correct (root) directory of my project, the exact same file path that the error is printing. I've tried putting it in other directories as well.

According to [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1043#issuecomment-97249646), it sounds like sound files should be able to be packaged using require() as well?

Just doing a test, requiring an image works perfectly:
`var image = require('./image.png');`

Comment: We can use webpack to `require` asset like mp3 file, could you check https://github.com/mjohnston/react-native-webpack-server

Comment: @DavidGuan Thanks for the info! But based on this discussion, isn't it supposed to be built in to React Native?: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1043#issuecomment-97249646

Comment: Have you looked at the example for loading sounds in the library you've said you're using? It doesn't look to me like you've imported the sound correctly https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound#basic-usage

Comment: @JosephRoque Yeah, I was trying to avoid that implementation (dropping each sound file into Xcode as well as an Android directory) -- I was going off of this ticket, which is suggesting that it could likely be done simply with require(): https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/14

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was simply using the app name as root:

```js
import myMP3File from '<appname>/assets/mymp3.mp3';
const Sound = require('react-native-sound');
Sound.setCategory('Playback');

// Do whatever you like with it.
Sound(myMP3File, () => console.log('soundfile loaded!'));
```

Edit:

We now use [`rn-fetch-blob`](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) and the following solution to access local files:

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;
filePathIos = `${fs.dirs.MainBundleDir}/yourFolder/yourMp3.mp3`;
filePathAndroid = fs.asset('yourFolder/yourMp3.mp3');
```

The corresponding path can then be used to copy the file using `fs.cp()`.

Comment: Did you had success on android . Also where do you get the appname. Is it taken from packag.json file ?

Comment: added our solution to the answer. <appname> referred to the name of the main folder iirc.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for us is to put the audio files we want to ship with the app in an `assets` directory and then have Xcode copy those files into the app bundle at build time. At that point, you can calculate the full path to the file using something like react-native-fs, and provide that to react-native-sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with managed Expo when trying to play a `sound.ogg`.
None of the trick I could find worked.
In the end, what solved it was to convert the `ogg` file to `mp3`, which is supported by Expo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [react-native-asset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset) to put files to your project and access them with `require` keyword.

Example for file with path `./assets/audio/some-audio.mp3`:

1. Add or modify `react-native.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
 project: {
   ios: {},
   android: {},
 },
 dependencies: {
 },
 assets: [
   './assets/audio'
 ],
};
```

2. Run `npx react-native-asset`
3. Use the file:

```js
const someAudio = require('./assets/audio/some-audio.mp3')
```